# Url for Twitter json feed for user

Tags: json, api, twitter

How can I find the url for my Twitter json feed? I have searched the Twitter docs and stackoverflow but I cannot seem to find a good answer. Most of the info I have found are from version 1 of the Twitter api which does not work anymore. Seems like this should be pretty easy...

Comment: **Note:** This can't be done client-side anymore. Not sure if that's what you're doing but hope that helps a little. More info?

Comment: Wow didn't realize that... Yes more info would be great! I am trying to develop a feed for my company that would bring in recent tweets, Instagram photos, recent songs we listened to on Spotify, and our recent blog posts. Gonna be kinda tough but it should turn out well!

Answer (score 0):

Because of your project having a lot of moving parts I suggest the use of an API wrapper in your specific server-side language. This will ease up the amount of work needed to get started.

A [Github Search](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=twitter%20api) reveals a ton of available projects that easily allow you to contact the api server.